# Given a list of country ISO codes and corresponding values, make a heatmap of a worldmap in python

Tags: python, data-visualization

I have a list of country ISO codes and a list of corresponding values. I would like to make a heatmap of the world where each country has a color representing a high or low value on some color scale. What is the best way to do this in python? For example the list of ISO codes might be ['GBR', 'USA'] and the value [0.1,0.2].

Answer (score 0):

Try to master "folium" library, It will help you a lot with map things.

Comment: Hello, please specify how you would answer the question with a code snippet.